# can't get session variable set before _redirectSuccess in controller

Tags: magento-1.9, session

in rewrite customer controller, in session, custom var 'email' is set:

```
if(!empty($customer_data)){

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    // or $session = $this->_getSession();
    $session->setEmail($email);
    // or  $email   = $session->setData('email', $email);
    Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setMySessionVariable($email); 
    $this->_redirectSuccess($this->_getUrl('*/*/customerChoice/'));

    ...

    }
```

then, on other customer controller's action, in which i redirect from the code above, i do:

```
public function customerChoiceAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    // or $session = $this->_getSession();

    $email   = $session->getEmail();
    // or  $email   = $session->getData('email');
```

but i get null in result, where to dig and hove to solve? thanks!

**UPDATE**

THIS WAS ONLY GOOGLE CHROME ISSUE, IN FIREFOX EVERYTHIG IS OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try bellow code:

**Data set in session**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setAbcemail('xyz@gmail.com');
```

**Data get in session**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAbcemail();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using,

```
 Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getMySessionVariable();
```

Try above method.